# BlueImp jQuery File Upload and ModSecurity Errors

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp, mod-security

<del>I'm getting intermittent errors from batch uploads using BlueImp.  I have used this same code/config on other LAMP machines without issue.</del>

Over the course of an hour my working batch upload using BlueImp went from accepting any file I threw at it to throwing ModSecurity errors on every upload.  I have contacted host to see if my IP is flagged or something of that nature.

Given the the BlueImp code involved is massive I am not posting all my code with this, only the initialization from [UploadHandler.php](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php).

Has anyone has run into this before or if anyone have advice re first steps for debugging this?

Errors:

```
[Thu Apr 02 09:58:44 2015] [error] [client 72.211.122.10] ModSecurity: Input filter: Failed writing 4380 bytes to temporary file (rc 523). [hostname "www.mysite.com"] [uri "/blueimp/server/php/"] [unique_id "VR11M83E320AACugsU0AAAAI"]
[Thu Apr 02 09:58:44 2015] [error] [client 72.211.122.10] ModSecurity: Multipart parsing error: Multipart: writing to "/tmp/20150402-095817-VR11Kc3E320AACohTxMAAAAE-file-KiCWWc" failed [hostname "www.mysite.com"] [uri "/blueimp/server/php/"] [unique_id "VR11Kc3E320AACohTxMAAAAE"]
```

UploadHandler.php:

```
<?php
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Class 8.3.1
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

class UploadHandler
{

    protected $options;

    // PHP File Upload error message codes:
    // http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
    protected $error_messages = array(
        1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini',
        2 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form',
        3 => 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded',
        4 => 'No file was uploaded',
        6 => 'Missing a temporary folder',
        7 => 'Failed to write file to disk',
        8 => 'A PHP extension stopped the file upload',
        'post_max_size' => 'The uploaded file exceeds the post_max_size directive in php.ini',
        'max_file_size' => 'File is too big',
        'min_file_size' => 'File is too small',
        'accept_file_types' => 'Filetype not allowed',
        'max_number_of_files' => 'Maximum number of files exceeded',
        'max_width' => 'Image exceeds maximum width',
        'min_width' => 'Image requires a minimum width',
        'max_height' => 'Image exceeds maximum height',
        'min_height' => 'Image requires a minimum height',
        'abort' => 'File upload aborted',
        'image_resize' => 'Failed to resize image'
    );

    protected $image_objects = array();

    function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
        $this->response = array();
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
            'upload_dir' => '/home/audubonimages/audubonimages.nolaflash.com/media/',
            'upload_url' => '/media/',
            'user_dirs' => true,
            'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
            'param_name' => 'files',
            // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
            // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
            'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
            'access_control_allow_origin' => '*',
            'access_control_allow_credentials' => false,
            'access_control_allow_methods' => array(
                'OPTIONS',
                'HEAD',
                'GET',
                'POST',
                'PUT',
                'PATCH',
                'DELETE'
            ),
            'access_control_allow_headers' => array(
                'Content-Type',
                'Content-Range',
                'Content-Disposition'
            ),
            // Enable to provide file downloads via GET requests to the PHP script:
            //     1. Set to 1 to download files via readfile method through PHP
            //     2. Set to 2 to send a X-Sendfile header for lighttpd/Apache
            //     3. Set to 3 to send a X-Accel-Redirect header for nginx
            // If set to 2 or 3, adjust the upload_url option to the base path of
            // the redirect parameter, e.g. '/files/'.
            'download_via_php' => false,
            // Read files in chunks to avoid memory limits when download_via_php
            // is enabled, set to 0 to disable chunked reading of files:
            'readfile_chunk_size' => 10 * 1024 * 1024, // 10 MiB
            // Defines which files can be displayed inline when downloaded:
            'inline_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',
            // Defines which files (based on their names) are accepted for upload:
            'accept_file_types' => '/.+$/i',
            // The php.ini settings upload_max_filesize and post_max_size
            // take precedence over the following max_file_size setting:
            'max_file_size' => null,
            'min_file_size' => 1,
            // The maximum number of files for the upload directory:
            'max_number_of_files' => null,
            // Defines which files are handled as image files:
            'image_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',
            // Use exif_imagetype on all files to correct file extensions:
            'correct_image_extensions' => false,
            // Image resolution restrictions:
            'max_width' => null,
            'max_height' => null,
            'min_width' => 1,
            'min_height' => 1,
            // Set the following option to false to enable resumable uploads:
            'discard_aborted_uploads' => true,
            // Set to 0 to use the GD library to scale and orient images,
            // set to 1 to use imagick (if installed, falls back to GD),
            // set to 2 to use the ImageMagick convert binary directly:
            'image_library' => 1,
            // Uncomment the following to define an array of resource limits
            // for imagick:
            /*
            'imagick_resource_limits' => array(
                imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MAP => 32,
                imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY => 32
            ),
            */
            // Command or path for to the ImageMagick convert binary:
            'convert_bin' => 'convert',
            // Uncomment the following to add parameters in front of each
            // ImageMagick convert call (the limit constraints seem only
            // to have an effect if put in front):
            /*
            'convert_params' => '-limit memory 32MiB -limit map 32MiB',
            */
            // Command or path for to the ImageMagick identify binary:
            'identify_bin' => 'identify',
            'image_versions' => array(
                // The empty image version key defines options for the original image:
                '' => array(
                    // Automatically rotate images based on EXIF meta data:
                    'auto_orient' => true
                ),
                'medium' => array(
                    'max_width' => 800,
                    'max_height' => 600
                ),
                'thumbnail' => array(
                    // Uncomment the following to use a defined directory for the thumbnails
                    // instead of a subdirectory based on the version identifier.
                    // Make sure that this directory doesn't allow execution of files if you
                    // don't pose any restrictions on the type of uploaded files, e.g. by
                    // copying the .htaccess file from the files directory for Apache:
                    //'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/thumb/',
                    //'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/thumb/',
                    // Uncomment the following to force the max
                    // dimensions and e.g. create square thumbnails:
                    //'crop' => true,
                    'max_width' => 80,
                    'max_height' => 80
                )
            ),
            'print_response' => true
        );
        if ($options) {
            $this->options = $options + $this->options;
        }
        if ($error_messages) {
            $this->error_messages = $error_messages + $this->error_messages;
        }
        if ($initialize) {
            $this->initialize();
        }
    }

    protected function initialize() {
        switch ($this->get_server_var('REQUEST_METHOD')) {
            case 'OPTIONS':
            case 'HEAD':
                $this->head();
                break;
            case 'GET':
                $this->get($this->options['print_response']);
                break;
            case 'PATCH':
            case 'PUT':
            case 'POST':
                $this->post($this->options['print_response']);
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                $this->delete($this->options['print_response']);
                break;
            default:
                $this->header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
        }
    }

    [snip]
```

After this is all default functions from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

Answer (score 0):

In this case it turned out that my host has the /tmp for my VPS outside my VPS and it was full.